# Test if a prediction was correct

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am working on the following problem:

- For a series of occupations, on one side I have a prediction from a couple of years ago on whether they will disappear or not (i.a. a percentage)
- On the other side I have the number of people employed in those occupations for each year since the prediction was made.

I want to test if the prediction was correct or not. What would be the appropriate statistical test to do this?

Comment: Some details are missing. What exactly does the prediction specify - the percentage of people that will be employed with this occupation? Are the predictions with regards to a certain year or time span?

Comment: The prediction specifies that an occupation has a certain probability of computerisation, _e.g. Personal Financial Advisors_, have a 58% probability of being computerised. My source does not say by when.

Comment: Then you would have to add assumptions. You can try to model the trend - fit a regression line to it and see if it would reach the predicted value in say, 5 years. Or ;you could assume the prediction was the probability of being computerized until 2020 (or your most current data) and calculate P(y% computerized by 2020 | x% predicted to be computerized by 2020)